# Parsing issue in mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am a newbie in `mongoDb` and I am using `mongoose` and `nodejs`. I am using the following in my server.js

Snippet of server.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.render('index', {
    courseList: courses
    });

});

app.get('/addcourse', function(req, res) {

    res.render('addcourse', {
    courseList: courses
    });

});

app.post('/addcourse', function(req, res) {
    // res.render('addcourse',{courseList:courses});
    // res.send("Data Recieved");
    //Create a new course
    var course = new Course({
    name: req.body.coursename,
    published: req.body.date,
    featured: req.body.feat
    });
    //The Magic!
    course.save(function(err, doc) {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    else res.redirect('/viewcourse');
    });
    res.render('viewcourse', {
    Courses: docs
    });
    //res.send("Done!");
});

app.get('/viewcourse', function(req, res) {
    Course.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) res.json(err);
    else res.render('viewcourse', {
        Courses: docs
    });
    });
});
```

Now I am submitting the values from `addcourse` file and trying to retrieve the data from the `MongoDb` and save in `viewcouse`. But when I am trying to retrieve data, I am getting following error.

```
 ReferenceError: docs is not defined
```

I know `res.render(viewcourse)` is wrong but I don't know how to fetch the value from database.

Please help me out.

Comment: Could it be that the line 'res.render('viewcourse',{Courses: docs});' has the  var docs, but docs has not been defined yet?

Comment: @Continuity8 How do I display the data in the Html any idea,,I got that docs is not defined.Any way around this

Comment: Your `POST /addcourse` route is refering to an undefined `docs` variable. Also, where exactly is the `ReferenceError` coming from? If it's from your template, it's refering to a `docs` variable which should probably be `Courses`.

Comment: @robertklep What changes should I make in the file..The error is coming in the template